# Grid Centring around Divider

Tags: style, grid-layouts, display, grid-lines

Consider the following `Grid`

```
Grid[{
  {123456, ""},
  {123, 12},
  {3, 1234}
  }, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]
```

which yields

[image]

My goal is to get the grid in the following shape (manually edited)

[image]

that is, while the second and third rows are aligned according to `Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}`, the first row has only one cell centred around the mid-vertical divider in the grid. Notice that it's not centred with respect to the cell, though this is also interesting.

How can I achieve this?

I'm aware of `SpanFromLeft`, which I tried in the following code

```
Grid[{
  {123456, SpanFromLeft},
  {123, 12},
  {3, 1234}
  }, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]
```

that is,

[image]

This gets me close, however the `123456` cell is not quite centred. Even closer is the code

```
Grid[{
  {123456, SpanFromLeft},
  {"", 123, 12},
  {"", 3, 1234}
  }, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Center, Right, Left}, Automatic}]
```

yielding

[image: C]

But the grid has an "extra" undesired column.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Following kglr's answer below, consider the case

```
Grid[{{Item[123456, Alignment -> Center], SpanFromLeft}, {123, 12}, {3, 1234567890}}, 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

This indeed yields a centred `123456`, within the respective cell. As mentioned before, however, is it possible to automatically centre it with respect to the mid-vertical divider? I want something like

[image]

Comment: See `Grid` documentation for specifying `Alignment`.  Then try `Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, {{Automatic}}, {{1, 1} -> Center}}`.

Comment: Thank you @Edmund, but that solves partially my question. I don't understand why my question was closed. I actually asked for two things, one of which seems actually trickier than that. Please see the 'edit' section for clarification and please reconsider its closure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update 2:** A function that takes a list of cell indices and  a `Grid` object to interactively adjust the alignments and paste the input form of the selected configuration:

```
ClearAll[alignCells]
alignCells[items : {{_, _} ..}] := DynamicModule[{n = Length@items, g = #,
   a = Table[0, Length@items]}, 
  Panel @ 
   Column[{Grid[Table[With[{j = j}, {items[[j]], 
       Manipulator[Dynamic[a[[j]]], {-1, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]}], {j, n}]], 
     Button["Paste", Manipulate`PasteSnapshot[Grid@g]], 
     Table[With[{j = j}, g[[1, ## & @@ items[[j]]]] = 
        Pane[g[[1, ## & @@ items[[j]]]], ImageSize -> {Full, All}, 
         Alignment -> {Dynamic@a[[j]], Center}]], {j, n}]; 
     MapAt[Item[#, Background -> LightYellow] &, g, Prepend[#, 1] & /@ items]}]]&;
```

***Examples:***

```
grid1 = Grid[{{123456, SpanFromLeft}, {123, 12}, {3, 1234567890}}, 
   Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}, ItemSize -> {{2, 7}, 1}]
```

[image]

```
alignCells[{{1, 1}}] @ grid1
```

[image]

Click `Paste` button to get

```
Grid[{{Pane[123456, ImageSize -> {Full, All}, 
    Alignment -> {Dynamic[FE`a$$860[[1]]], 
      Center}], \[SpanFromLeft]}, {123, 12}, {3, 1234567890}}, 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}, 
 ItemSize -> {{2, 7}, 1}]
```

and evaluate to get

[image]

```
grid2 = Grid[{{123456, SpanFromLeft, 13}, {123, 12, 23}, {3, 
     1234567890, 33}, {41, 1234, SpanFromLeft}, {1, 2, 3}}, 
   Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left, Left}, Automatic}, 
   ItemSize -> {{2, 7, 3}, 1}]
```

[image]

```
alignCells[{{1, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}}] @ grid2
```

[image]

Click the `Paste` button and evaluate the resulting cell to get

[image]

**Update:**  ***"is it possible to automatically center it with respect to the mid-vertical divider?"***

I don't know of any *automatic* way to get the first row aligned with the column divider.

A semi-manual approach is possible:

1. Specify the `ItemSize`s in grid options, and
2. Wrap the first cell content with `Pane` with the options `ImageSize -> {Full,
   All}` and `Alignment -> {a, Center}` and adjust `a` to get the
   desired position.
3. Use `PasteSnapshot` button in `Manipulate` and evaluate the pasted
   cell to get the desired output.

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{Pane[123456, ImageSize -> {Full, All}, 
     Alignment -> {a, Center}], SpanFromLeft}, 
    {123, 12}, {3, 1234567890}}, Frame -> All, 
  Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}, 
  ItemSize -> {{Scaled[.05], Scaled[.1]}, 1}],
{{a, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Use specific sizes, e.g., `ItemSize -> {{2, 7}, 1}`, if you do not want the cell sizes change with the notebook window size.

**Original answer:**

```
Grid[{{123456, SpanFromLeft}, {123, 12}, {3, 1234}}, Frame -> All, 
 Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic, {{1, 1} -> Center}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, assign cell-specific alignments using `Item`:

```
Grid[{{Item[123456, Alignment -> Center], SpanFromLeft}, {123, 12}, {3, 1234}}, 
 Frame -> All, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}]
```

> same picture