# Centering a weirdly shaped grid

Tags: style, grid-layouts, alignment, grid-lines

Consider the following grid

```
Grid[{
  {"Center", SpanFromLeft, 111},
  {"ThisIsAVeryLongString", "ThisIsAVeryLongString", 111},
  {"Center", SpanFromLeft}
  }, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Is it possible to centre the top `"Center"` string with respect to the grid, aligning it with the bottom `"Center"` string? Something like

[image]

Notice that a consequence of this is that, in cases where I have a shorter second row, I can get

[image]

which is fine either way. Any ideas?

Comment: You could add leading spaces

Comment: @mikado You mean to the left of the string?

Comment: Yes...............

Comment: Perhaps not the best option, as it will vary according to the string and grid sizes, unless I could make it automatic. I guess if there's a way of tracking the relative position of the bottom `"Center"`, I could maybe force the placement of the top one.

Comment: related/may be useful: [Grid Centering around Divider](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212116/125)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it's not super nice, you can use `Item[Invisible[...],...]` to do this:

```
Grid[{
  {Item[Invisible@111, Frame -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, False}], "Center", SpanFromLeft, 111}, 
  {"ThisIsAVeryLongString", SpanFromLeft, "ThisIsAVeryLongString", 111}, 
  {"Center", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}},
  Frame -> All
]
```

[image]

As you can see, the idea is to effectively make an additional column at the far left that has exactly the same width as the last one, but is invisible. Of course, this might not be easy to achieve in all cases.

Comment: +1 from me.  I never knew about `Invisible`.  It solves a wide range of issues.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Extended comment.

While I very much like @Lukas_Lang's answer, (`Invisible` has been invisible to me ;-), I don't get the result that he gets running on my Version 12.3.1.0 for macOS. e.g.,

```
Grid[{
  {Item[Invisible@111, Frame -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, False}], "Center", SpanFromLeft, 111}, 
  {"ThisIsAVeryLongString", SpanFromLeft, "ThisIsAVeryLongString", 111}, {"Center", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}},
  Frame -> All
]
```

yields...

[image]

A simple switch around solves the issue...

```
Grid[{
  {Item[Invisible@111],
   Item["Center", Frame -> {Automatic, False, Automatic, Automatic}],
   SpanFromLeft, 111}, {"ThisIsAVeryLongString", SpanFromLeft, 
   "ThisIsAVeryLongString", 111}, {"Center", SpanFromLeft, 
   SpanFromLeft}},
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

This will get strange if @Lukas_Lang also uses Version 12.3.1.0 running on macOS.

Comment: Could use `Item[Invisible@111, Frame -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Opacity[0]}]` instead of giving "Center" a frame.